# Efficient method of writing C++ code in Windows IDE and compiling in Linux terminal?

Tags: c++, ide

First of all, it's all about maximizing the productivity as a c++ programmer. My regular work is to use Windows ssh client such as `xshell` to log in to remote linux machine via ssh and do many linux work there. Imagine I want to set up a big C++ project, and now I'm faced with a trouble.

- If I write code in Windows IDE, I need to propagate the changes every time I modify some files to linux machine, and compile there. (Consider compiling in Windows is not feasible or very slow)
- If I write code in linux terminal, as it's gonna be a big project(not just a simple hellowrold), the productivity in working on vim or emacs cannot match with  that in Windows IDE.

Here I want to exclude some options such as `samba`, configuring many plugins for vim, or just buy a Mac. And if I write in Windows, it's undesirable to copy the whole contents to remote machine every time syncing with it.

Any ways or tools to make this process easier and productive ?

Comment: How about using `git`?

Comment: How about a virtual machine?

Comment: Personally, I'd just do everything remotely, but I'm also way more productive and have a better workflow using emacs than some ide.

Comment: I’ve seen a lot of people mention git, but I didn’t see anyone mention that you can also setup Continuous Integration to automatically pull and compile code when a commit comes in.

Comment: @newkid  git seems not be an option. Sometimes the changes are not a complete commit, so it's very undesiable to make codebase full of uncomplete modifications.

Comment: @Shawn Any blogs about your workflow ?

Comment: A blog? Lol no. Write code, compile, debug, repeat.

Comment: Now vscode + remote ssh is best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just use VirtualBox:

1. Create a VM containing your favorite flavor of Linux
2. Create a project in your Windows IDE of choice - I use VS2015 at the mo.
3. Set the VS project directory as an external mount point/shared folder of the VM. So all code changes are intrinsically available to the Linux machine.
4. When its time to compile just alt-tab to the VM windows and type make (assuming you've create your MakeFile ;) )

Comment: That seems a solution, but not good for me. Starting a VM on Windows will slow down other apps. Besides the c++ project I build consumes much more resources when compiling.

Comment: Not only that VMs are very impractical for performance reasons, but VirtualBox is aweful anyway. It's very slow. I used VMWare for years, but it's kind of impractical to keep everything on your laptop. At some point your laptop can't handle all the memory required for debugging and memory analysis. My ideal solution is ssh to my workstation and use it. This depends on whether your apps are "Hello World!" or ones with 2000 source files. For small apps... who cares? VM is fine.

Comment: Fair points. An adaptation of this would be to run Linux on a separate physical machine and share/mount the project directory over the LAN. Just 'optioneering'. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

- **Option 1:** Use [mobaxterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) (which is a very fast xserver on windows) to run your IDE. I run Qt Creator over the internet and it's instantaneous, so no lags.
- **Option 2:** Use VNC only for that program. So create some VNC server and run your IDE in it. This doesn't work for me because the VNC server (realvnc I think) crashes all the time. Maybe you'll be lucky.
- **Option 3:** Use VNC with desktop environment. I got this to work at work, but not at home. It depends on what desktop environment you want to use, something like icewm is fine (the command on linux is `vncserver` for that).
- **Option 4:** Use [X2Go](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php) as your remote environment. Install the server on your linux, and connect to it with ssh.
- **Option 5:** Use [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/) protocol. Install it on linux, and use windows remote desktop to connect to your linux machine from windows.

**Warning:** If you're using VNC, be aware that the standard VNC implementation doesn't provide encrypted connection. So you should use something like ssh tunnel (with putty, or similar) from Windows to Linux, then tunnel your VNC connection through it.

Comment: Thanks for many options. For Option 1, I'm very curious. Do you mean you can install QtCreator(which is one of my favourite IDE) on linux and run it via mobaxtem on Windows ?

Comment: @LewisChan Yes. This is what I do all the time. You're gonna love it! The only problem there is that you can't save your sessions. So if your laptop (Windows machine) shuts down, you'll have to restart Qt Creator. Also if the connection gets interrupted, it'll close. Mobaxterm, however, does everything it can to keep the session connected. Some times even if I forcibly disconnect my wifi.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I work in this situation:

1. setup a distant Git repo
2. use your regular workstation to edit your code (Windows OS), using the IDE that suits you needs
3. keep a shell open on your remote Linux machine (SSH)
4. As soon as you have something runnable/testable:

   1. `commit` your changes and `git push`
   2. in your Linux Shell: `git pull` & build (`make` ?)

Comment: The thing is, before compiling I may  make some unware mistakes such as grammar errors, spelling errors or logical errors. I don't think the changes can make a resonable commit .

Comment: You have a point. But 1-unless some really specific situation, there shouldn't be a reason not to be able to build on Windows. 2-sure, erroneous commits are not desirable, but they can be squashed afterwards if that is really annoying. But, sure, remote viewing (other answer) is also a nice idea.

Comment: I don't believe anyone in the world really uses this solution and really gets results for huge programs. I'm just imagining the amount of time wasted committing, pushing, building (with make parallelization since you have templates in your program and want to finish fast), then having to scroll up and down to see that you typed `cot` instead of `cout`... then going back to your IDE, fix it, commit, push, and go back again to terminal, to see that you missed a semi-colon somewhere else. I would quit programming before having to do this. Are you gonna scroll through all of it to find warnings?

Comment: [...] I build with Qt Creator with Ctrl+b. It shows me warnings immediately. It also uses clang model to predict compilation errors before compiling. I run valgrind with 1 click to do memory checks for my final program. I run debugger with 1 click, and can navigate through my debugged code without having to type `up` `up` `up` to reach my current stack frame. Because I click on the stack frame I want. I run function profiling with 1 click. I will never understand how people get work done with terminals only. Well, maybe in the 1990s. But now you have Qt Creator and/or VSCode for this luxury.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I agree this workflow isn't the best. But what if you don't have a desktop on the remote machine?

Comment: @kebs We all went into these situations, but then it's not a full dev environment that you can suggest to OP! He's asking for a convenient setup for his development. You can't suggest a temporary solution to a temporary problem for someone who's looking for a permanent setup. And to answer your question: You install a desktop on that machine if you have to. Otherwise, it's not a proper machine for permanent development.